# Show color option in FontDialog with no underline and strikeout options

Tags: .net, winforms, colors

I am using `FontDialog` control in VB.NET application.

When I set its `ShowColor` property to `true`, it shows me *Strikeout*, *Underline* and *Color* option under *Effects* group. I need only *Color* from these three.

Is there any way to hide *Strikeout* and *Underline* effects, so that only *Color* option will be visible?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Is there any alternate way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to hide or change default Windows font dialog.

For that you have to create your own custom control.

Answer (score 1):

- Derive `ColorDialog` class
- Override `HookProc` method
- Handle `WM_INITDIALOG` message (272)
- Hide respective dialog items

This is similar to what the `ColorDialog` class does when you set `ShowColor = false` and `ShowEffects = true` (what is default):

```
protected override IntPtr HookProc(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
{
  switch (msg)
  {
    case 272:
      if (!this.showColor)
      {
        SafeNativeMethods.ShowWindow(new HandleRef((object) null, UnsafeNativeMethods.GetDlgItem(new HandleRef((object) null, hWnd), 1139)), 0);
        SafeNativeMethods.ShowWindow(new HandleRef((object) null, UnsafeNativeMethods.GetDlgItem(new HandleRef((object) null, hWnd), 1091)), 0);
        break;
      }
      else
        break;
  ...
}
```

The above hides the "Color" label and color combo (dialog IDs 1139 and 1091).

You want the opposite, hide the Strikeout and Underline. Their dialog IDs are 1040 and 1041 (found in Wine code).

---

Full implementation of "font and color" dialog by @HansPassant:

Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Compile.  Drop the new component from the top of the toolbox onto your form, replacing the existing `FontDialog`.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class MyFontDialog
    Inherits FontDialog

    Protected Overrides Function HookProc(hWnd As IntPtr, msg As Integer, wparam As IntPtr, lparam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
        If msg = 272 And Me.ShowColor Then  '' WM_INITDIALOG
            Dim strikeout = GetDlgItem(hWnd, &H410)
            If strikeout <> IntPtr.Zero Then ShowWindow(strikeout, 0)
            Dim underline = GetDlgItem(hWnd, &H411)
            If underline <> IntPtr.Zero Then ShowWindow(underline, 0)
        End If
        Return MyBase.HookProc(hWnd, msg, wparam, lparam)
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function GetDlgItem(hDlg As IntPtr, item As Integer) As IntPtr
    End Function
    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function ShowWindow(hWnd As IntPtr, cmd As Integer) As Boolean
    End Function
End Class
```

---

I actually needed this for a WinAPI (C++ Builder), so while slightly off-topic, I'm sharing the C++ WinAPI code too. It is more fancy, as it does even shift the *Color* box up:

```c
RECT Rect;
POINT Point;

HWND StrikeoutHandle = GetDlgItem(Handle, 1040);
GetWindowRect(StrikeoutHandle, &Rect);
POINT StrikeoutPoint = { Rect.left, Rect.top };
ScreenToClient(Handle, &StrikeoutPoint);

ShowWindow(StrikeoutHandle, SW_HIDE);
ShowWindow(GetDlgItem(Handle, 1041), SW_HIDE);

HWND LabelHandle = GetDlgItem(Handle, 1091);
GetWindowRect(LabelHandle, &Rect);
Point.x = Rect.left;
Point.y = Rect.top;
ScreenToClient(Handle, &Point);

int Shift = StrikeoutPoint.y - Point.y;

SetWindowPos(LabelHandle, NULL, Point.x, Point.y + Shift, 0, 0,
  SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);

HWND ComboHandle = GetDlgItem(Handle, 1139);
GetWindowRect(ComboHandle, &Rect);
Point.x = Rect.left;
Point.y = Rect.top;
ScreenToClient(Handle, &Point);
SetWindowPos(ComboHandle, NULL, Point.x, Point.y + Shift, 0, 0,
  SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);
```

The result is like:

[image: Font and color dialog]

Comment: I liked your idea and worked it out to a usable class.  Feel free to copy as you see fit and I'll delete my post.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's not possible to hide underline and strikeout option in fontdialog.
You can solve your problem by not showing such effects on your text by handling it just before style apply on the target text.